# Deny direct access to executing script

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I previously had below which worked ok,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ /news/index.php?post=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But I don't want it to open like this

```
https://example.com/news/index.php?post=123456
```

I want it to open only in such a way that it only allows numbers

```
https://example.com/news/123456
```

is the request that **/news/index.php?post=123456** should not resolve Only **/news/123456** should be accessible

Thanks

Comment: does this help? `RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/?$ /news/index.php?post=$1 [L,QSA]`. I believe you missed the part where the url should start with news/

Comment: I don't want it to open like this 
https://example.com/news/index.php?post=123456 
I want it to open only in such a way 
https://example.com/news/123456

Comment: to understand you correctly... You what to redirect https://example.com/123456 to https://example.com/news/123456?

Comment: Is the request that `/news/index.php?post=123456` should not resolve? Only `/news/123456` should be accessible

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: @ganjoali It's not really clear that is the intent with the question. Question as written seems like your rewrites aren't working. I've updated the title to what I think intent is. Please clarify if that is wrong

Comment: if the case is to redirect /123456 to /news/123456, you can use something like this RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ /news/$1 [L,QSA]. The $1 simbol take everyting from first bracket and put it after /news/

Comment: You need to use a RewriteCond here, to match & capture that `post` parameter value, and then redirect to your "fancy" URL instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need a combintation of both, an internal rewrite and an external redirection:

```
RewriteEngine on
# externally redirect direct requests to the actual resource
RewriteConf %{QUERY_STRING} ^post=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^/?news/index\.php$ /news/%1 [R=301,L]
# internally rewrite requests to pretty URLs
RewriteRule ^/?news/(\d+)$ /news/index.php?post=$1 [END]
```

It is a good idea to start out using a `R=302` *temporary* redirection and to only change that to a `R=301` *permanent* redirection once everything works as expected. That prevents caching issues with clients while you are still trying around.

Above rules will work likewise in the central http server's configuration *and* in a distributed configuration file (".htaccess"). If you have access to the central configuration then that should clearly be the preferred place to implement such rules.

Answer (score -1):

Hi to achieve this add the below lines and restart the services, where The provided rule ensures that the URL starts with "news/" and captures numeric values to append them to the URL as your expectation.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^news/(\d+)$ /news/index.php?post=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply
But I want to prevent it from opening up like this
https://example.com/news/index.php?post=123456

 If anyone does this, redirect them directly to this link
https://example.com/news/123456

Comment: What service should get restarted? If such a rule is implemented in a distributed configuration file, as suggested by the question's tags, then _nothing_ has to be restarted.